# Did Rom Mohc fight in the Battle of Utapau?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, revenge-of-the-sith

[Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rom_Mohc) states that

> [**Rom**] **Mohc** gained a reputation for fighting battle droids in
>   hand-to-hand combat and developed a keen understanding of cybernetics.

On the scene of the [Battle of Utapau](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Utapau/Legends), where Obi-Wan Kenobi jumps on his ride in order to pursuit General Grievous, we see a trooper fighting a Separatist droid, *bare-handed*! Could he be **Rom Mohc**?

[image]

Comment: Considering he's not canon, probably not. That's be a neat tip of that hat though. also how the heck did you spot that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

According to a variety of sources (notably the [Starwars.com databank](http://www.starwars.com/news/kaminos-finest-captains-and-commanders-of-the-clone-army)) excluding the Jedi, there were no non-clone commanders of the Grand Army of the Republic. As such, it would have been impossible for ***Commander*** Rom Mohc to have taken a personal part in the Battle of Utapau.

It's also worth noting that the person you've highlighted is a trooper, not a commander (given the absence of a pauldron) and given that all of the troopers in the Grand Army were in fact clones, it's also pretty unlikely that this individual was wandering around in Clone Trooper armour during the battle.

---

As noted in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126560/did-rom-mohc-fight-in-the-battle-of-utapau#comment316775_126560), Rom Mohc's sole appearance is in a couple of non-canon factbooks, a non-canon Star Wars shoot-em-up game and in some non-canon magazine articles (about the aforementioned game). While this may have been a 'tip-of-the-hat' to his character, it seems far more likely that this is just a random  background CGI trooper doing random background CGI trooper stuff.

Answer (score 1):

No, That is not Rom Mohc.

However, might I remind the above commentators that Rom Mohc *WAS* canon during the time of Revenge of the Sith's Release in 2005. It was not until 2014, following purchase from the Disney Corporation, that Rom Mohc was deemed *non-canon* (along with 37 years of stories sanctioned and approved by George Lucas and his company Lucasfilm LTD).

That being said in the old canon (now referred to as the "Legends" continuity and kept as an unofficial alternate timeline in the hearts of my die hard star wars fans), Rom Mohc was one of the many non-clone officers in the Grand Army of the Republic during the clone wars so he wouldn't be wearing Clone Trooper armor like the chap in the image above. He would have worn something more akin to the imperial officer uniforms you see in the Empire Strikes Back.

*edit

There is also no evidence that Rom Mohc was attached to the Third Systems Army (the sector army that Obi-wan and Commander Cody lead during the war).